# PHP: json_encode is truncating an object

Tags: php, json

I'm using Ajax to pass an object containing about 2000-3000 elements, all of them integers or short strings, to a php file. From what I can tell from debugging, the object is arriving intact into the php code. But it's being truncated when I run json_encode.

here's the passing function

```
function saveWerJSON (output) {
    console.log(output);
    $.post("writefile.php", output, function(output){ console.log("yes"); });
};
```

Here's the PHP file in its entirety

```
<?php 
file_put_contents("wer1861.json", json_encode($_POST,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
?>
```

the file cuts off after 1422 lines (length: 40300). The json in the file is valid. So the variable is getting truncated before it's written.

Is this a limitation of json_encode? I see that json_encode has a "depth" variable, but it doesn't seem to be well documented...

Comment: Is there a PHP error at the end of json? Might be a memory limitation.

Comment: what does `JSON.stringify(output).length` say on the server? JSON encoding on both ends should theoretically be identical, and the string lenths of the json on both ends should be identical as well.

Comment: @Joshua. I don't think it's memory. I can see the entire variable in the debugger.

Comment: @Marc JSON.stringify(output).length 21909 But after the Json encode it gets chopped down.

Comment: then do `console.log(JSON.stringify(output))` and `var_dump($_POST)` and compare the strings. length isn't enough to figure out what's going on. you need to look at what's INSIDE the strings.

Comment: try adding this to the top of your php file, this should give you an idea of what is happening:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I've used Chrome to see what's inside the javascript string and Firebug to see what's inside the php strings. output and $POST both have all the elements in the object. It's only when I run it through json_encode that it gets cut off.

Comment: Solved this with a workaround. I stringify in JavaScript and pass the string to php, which simply writes that. Thanks for your help.